# VBA Excel Do while and If condition

Tags: vba

Following code some times it work and for more than two values it says an error mentioning a overflow.
I just want to write a VBA code for a values in a column to separate three categories and count numbers in each category. please tell me the error of this code.

```
Sub income_status()

Dim income As Integer
Dim locount As Integer
Dim mecount As Integer
Dim hicount As Integer



Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    income = ActiveCell.Value


    If income <= 10000 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Low Income"
    locount = locount + 1

    ElseIf income > 10000 And income <= 50000 Then

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Medium Income"
    mecount = mecount + 1

    Else

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "High Income"
    hicount = hicount + 1


    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

  Loop
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = locount
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = mecount
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = hicount


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: You need to declare your variables as longs....`Dim income As Long`

Comment: You need to watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&t=3043s&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: For the future, as @DoronYakovlev-Golani mentioned, be sure to include the line that the error happened on and the exact error that you are receiving.  It makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot.  Welcome to StackOverflow!!!

Answer (score 2):

The max value of an integer is 32767.  Surely there is income higher than this, especially since you're checking for values higher than 50k.  Declare all of your variables as longs:

```
Dim income As Long
Dim locount As Long
Dim mecount As Long
Dim hicount As Long
```

and the rest should be the same.

Comment: "the rest should be the same" - yeah. Well, except for the crap indentation and the relying on `ActiveCell` and `.Select` ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Hahaha.  Very true.  Hopefully the OP will look at the link provided in comments to the question.  :)